# How to implement future-like operation in this scenario?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jdbc

Let's say I have some object that I store in a back end database (let's call it Thing).

```java
class Thing {

  private String id;
  private String name;

  public Thing(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  /* getters/setters/etc */
}
```

I also have a class which handles create, read, update, and delete operations for the `Thing` class; let's call it DatabaseManager. This class interacts asynchronously with an underlying postgresql database and I cannot modify it.

```java
class DatabaseManager {

  public void add(Thing t) {
    // ...
  }

  public ManagedThing get(String id) {
    // ...
  }

  public void update(String id, String name) {
    // ...
  }

  public void delete(String id) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

When things are added to this database, some asynchronous processes happen and a new object is created and registered called `ManagedThing`.

If I have a method called in my APIs that adds one of these Thing objects like so:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createThing(Bean bean) {
  var thing = new Thing(bean.getId(), bean.getName());
  /* validation */
  databaseManager.add(thing);
  /* async stuff triggered */
  ManagedThing mt = databaseManager.getThing(bean.getId());
  return new CreatedResponse(mt.toJson());
}
```

In this code above that I own and can modify; the only way I could possibly know when the new `ManagedThing` is finally created asynchronously is via a `PropertyChangeEvent` I have to register for. My question is; is there a way I could possibly block until the ManagedThing becomes available?

Comment: Sure, the general approach is to create a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) that is completed in the event callback. Then, the calling code can call [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) on it to block until it is completed. A proper answer should contain a code example. Can you update the question to show how you register to receive the event?

Comment: What if ManagedThing is already created before you have time to register a PropertyChangeEvent?